# How to get full interpreter startup banner

Tags: python, python-interactive

I am trying to get the startup banner info in Python, not just:

```py
f'''Python {sys.version} on {sys.platform}
Type "help", "copyright", "credits", or "license" for more information.'''
```

which results in:

```
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul 2 2020, 17:30:36) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

but the full startup banner including any errors and the distribution for example:

```
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 17:30:36) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated. Libraries may fail to load. To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation.

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I was thinking of running `python` in `subprocess.Popen` and then terminate it, but I have not been able to capture the startup banner output.

Comment: `subprocess` should have worked - did you capture both STDOUT and STDERR?  I'm not sure which channel those messages are sent to.

Comment: I still cannot get `subprocess` to work:
```import subprocess
from time import sleep

afil = open('r.txt', 'wb')
bfil = open('t.txt', 'wb')

sub = subprocess.Popen('cmd /k python', shell=True, stdout=afil, stderr=bfil)
sleep(5)
sub.terminate()
sub.kill()
afil.close()
bfil.close()``` gives me `\nC:/Users/Brainfart>` in `r.txt` and `\n` in `b.txt`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to figure this question out. Turns out `subprocess.Popen` was the right answer. Interestingly the header was printed to `stderr` instead of `stdout`.
Code that worked for me:

```py
from subprocess import (Popen, PIPE)
from os import devnull
from sys import executable
from time import sleep
nump = open(devnull, 'w+') #Making a dud file so the stdin won't be the same as the main interpreter
hed = Popen(executable, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=nump)
sleep(0.1) #Sleeping so python has time to print the header before we kill it
hed.terminate()
nump.close()
print(hed.stderr.read().decode('utf-8').strip().strip('>>>').strip()) #Removing whitespace and the '>>>'
```

Comment: Changed the subprocess call from using `python` to using `sys.executable`. This approach is better because it ensures that you get the header from the same python as your script is run in.